# Cannot add extension crx file chrome

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I can't add extensions crx file. Chrome always open but no extensions. did i do wrong somewhere?
one more thing i use undetected-chromedriver

`https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver`

my code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
...
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension('./capcha.crx')
options.add_extension('./metamask.crx')
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True,options = options,user_data_dir=path_profile_chrome)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
options.add_argument(
"--load-extension=path\\to\\extension1,path\\to\\extension2")
```